# EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid) Xcode 9.2

Tags: xcode, macos

I created an update for one of my iOS apps and in the next step, I wanted to port the changes to the macOS app.
I haven't changed the app in a while and once I fixed all the build errors and the project compiled successfully, I started the app.
After starting the app, it immediately crashed without any errors. When checking the log files, I found the following crash report:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

I already revoked all certificates and created new ones (also creating new provisioning profiles), but this didn't help either.

I am using XCode 9.2, does anyone know how to solve this issue? I am using macOS High Sierra 10.13

Comment: I narrowed it down to the maps entitlement. When I remove the entitlement, the app will start. But the maps entitlement is set in the provisioning profile :(

Comment: Although the App still crashes on my system, I submitted it for review. The update is now online and the release version of the Mac Store runs fine. When I open the Debug build, it still crashes. Very weird.